Time clauses reported speech
Time clauses in reported speech. Do we have to change what's in time clause in reported speech? Let me give examples
I will do it as soon as she comes.
She will cook when I tell her to.
He said he would do it as soon as she comes or came.
He said she would cook when I tell her or told her to.
Do we have to change it or it's fine to leave it?

"...or is it fine to leave it?"

Be aware that to tell someone to do something is not to tell someone something. Without the to, your sentences sound like the second. As in: I told her the secret.  I changed those by adding to because I think that is probably what you meant.

Context and intended meaning are everything. He said he would [or will] do it as soon as she comes implies that she has yet to come, whereas He said he would do it as soon as she came means she has already come.
Another similar sentence is He says he will do it as soon as she comes. Again depending on context, it might mean pretty much the same as the first pair. But the use of present-tense says can have a slight flavor of conveying that his promise definitely remains in force, whereas the first version in that first pair (He said he would…) would also  be okay if he had by now retracted the promise. As is so often remarked here on ELL, very, very much depends on context and intended meaning.
One variant that does not work is *He says he would do it as soon as she comes.

Can we backshift first part and leave the second one?

Yes, and I should have done so in my examples. I have edited them.

I'm tempted to downvote because you edited out He said he will do it as soon as she comes. AND you didn't include He says he will do it as soon as she comes. We don't want to give learners the impression any of these permutations are "better" than any others. It's just that in certain specific contexts, some don't work.

Yikes, @FumbleFingers, I am glad you gave me advance warning. I shall remedy the flaw with all alacrity.

Well, I just hope any edit will be because you agree with me (not because you're after +1 rather than -1 on your reputation tally! :)

Well @FumbleFingers, I did characterize it as a flaw. And it’s one that has made an indelible black mark on my good name.

Arguably, Present Tense He says he'll do it as soon as... implies greater confidence that he will do it than Past Tense He said he'd do it as soon as... In practice I doubt many people consciously take that into account when choosing their phrasing (and even less audiences would consciously pick up on that subtlety), but obviously both forms do in fact occur.

@FumbleFingers, I have edited further, so you may now wish to wield that downvote.

What about this one? "I did it when she came". He said he had done it when she came or had came. Here both have excatly the same meaning right?

What about it? I mean what are you asking?

I still don’t understand what you’re now asking. And anyway, if you have a further question, you should consider posting it as a new question. And if it involves differences among several sentences, you should describe what you think those differences are and why you think so.

@Adam: The actual utterance "I did it when she came" would normally be reported as He said he did it when she came. Note that He said he did it when she had came is wildly ungrammatical, and no native speaker would ever say that. On the other hand, He said he did it when she had come is syntactically fine - just excruciatingly non-idiomatic. As ever, What meaning do you want to convey? I don't see what you learn from shuffling elements around and asking what some given permutation means.
