reporting time clauses in the past and future

When she came I was cooking

I cook when he comes


Am I right that because 1 is in the past we can report that sentence in three was and the meaning wil be the same?
1a. He said he had been cooking when she came
1b. He said he was cooking when she came
1c. He said he had been cooking when she had come
All three are correct with the same meaning (obviously 3 isn't natural at all but possible), correct?
2 example is not in the past and because of that we can report this in three ways but the meaning may be different
2a. He said he cooks when he comes
2b. He said  he cooked when she comes
2c. He said he cooked when she came
A and B imply it is still true or yet to happen. C shows is it no loner true. Correct?

The numbering is off, but in the first 3, only the second works: "He said he was cooking when she came." We have no information about "had been" earlier, only at the time she arrived.

Is this question really different from your other one about time?

2b doesn't work. 2a is describing a regular occurrence (he cooks a meal whenever she visits him), 2c a regular occurrence in the past (though he used to cook would be more natural).

@KateBunting I understand what they mean but I struggle with how to transform them into reported speech. When we have simple sentences it is easy like " I cook" becomes "he said she cooked". Somehow when we have clauses it all beomes mixed up and blurry.

On the other hand "I will do it when she finishes it" could be transform into "he said he would do it when she  finishes it". Can you explain why here it is fine to backshift only one part of my sentence but when it comes to my original example that's wrong?

If you don't mind please comment on this example , too " I'm going to sleep all the time when we get there". Could we transform that into "he said he was going to sleep all the time when we get there"?

Both of these last two depend on whether the second event has happened or not. "He said that he's going to sleep all the time when we get there" (they are still on the journey). "He said that he was going to sleep all the time when we got there" (the journey is in the past, and the speaker is recalling something that was said during it.)

Similarly "I cook" becomes "He said that she cooks" if she still does so.

@KateBunting we could also say "He said he was going to sleep all the time  when we get there" and it measn that they are still on the journey. So we changed only one part of the sentence. That's why I'm asking why this doesn't work "He said he cooked when she comes". Even though here too only one part is backshifted.

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/352679/time-clauses-reported-speech here Paul shows that such changes are possible

And he says 'it very much depends on context or intended meaning'. What do you intend that sentence to mean? It makes no sense to me.

@KateBunting I just want to understand how to reported sentences with time clauses. I know how to do it when it is in the past "I was cooking when she arrived" but don"t know how to do it when it comes to the present and related to future sentences.


I am going to do it when she arrives 2. I cooked when she arrived. Can you give me all possible opitions of reporting whether suggesting it is still true or not?


The 'still true' thing is not relevant here. "He said/says that he is going to do it when she arrives" (she hasn't arrived yet). "He said that he was going to do it when she arrived" (her arrival is in the past).

@KateBunting Two questions. 1) Why do you say "he was going to do it when she arrived" (her arrival is in the past)"? We are allowed to backshift even if something is still true. So, can it be that her arrival is still in the future?       2) Paul presented this example "He said he would  do it as soon as she comes? Do you think it is correct or "will" should be used? Note the direct sentence was "I will do it when she comes"?


I have just told you that the 'still true' thing is not relevant to your examples - it refers to sentences like "He said that the sun rose/rises in the East". If her arrival is in the past, of course we use the past tense! 2. Yes, that sentence is perfectly idiomatic.


Some of your examples are correct, but there are several errors and misunderstandings. So overall, no, this is not the right way to think about tenses. My advice to you is to keep it simple. Choose one or two sentences at a time. Learn them and understand them as completely as you can. Wait until you have mastered them before trying out other examples.
In that spirit, I'm not going to answer every example. I'm going to pick one case and explain it in detail. You wrote this:

1a. He said he had been cooking when she came.
2a. He said he was cooking when she came.
3a. He said he had been cooking when she had come.
All three are correct with the same meaning (obviously 3 isn't natural at all but possible), correct?

First, consider sentence (3b). You say it's not natural. So why are you even considering it? Don't focus on complex sentences. I won't say that it is certainly wrong, but I will say this: I have been thinking for over 5 minutes and I can't think of an example where (3a) is necessary. I thought of one or two possible sentences, but in real life I would never have used them. I would always have simplified them to the simple past tense as in sentence (2b).
Second, read sentences (1a) and (2a) again. They do not have the same meaning. Again, my advice is: Do not go any further until you know clearly what that difference is.
If you can't see it, compare the same tenses in direct speech. Imagine John at home, and Susan walks into the house. John says one of the following:

1a. "Hi Sue. I'm in the kitchen. I'm cooking."

or...

"Hi Sue. I'm in the kitchen. I've been cooking."

Do you see that these are two clearly different tenses? And do you see that you have retained those different tenses when you converted them to indirect speech?
Note that context matters. No doubt we could create a context where these sentences did have the same meaning. But we would probably find that it was a very complex example, and in real life we would simplify it anyway.

I have seen this sentence "I will do it when you arrive" being reported in three different ways 1) He said he will do that when you arrive 2) He said he would do that when you arrive 3) He said he would do it when you arrived. 1 and 2 indicate it is still true. That's how I made my examples refering to my second example "I cook when she comes". Can you comment on that?

This is a complex example, and it shows the importance of my answer. Get the basics right. It's complex because you are relating at least three different times; when he will do it; when you arrive; and when he said lies in relation to those two other times. Those times can all vary, and all your answers might or might not be right. And even if they are right, the context may allow an easier way of saying it all.
